# How to create a new default keyfile/keyring for Domino

Tags: ssl-certificate, ibm-domino, lotus-notes

I am in the process of moving from **Web Configuration** to **Internet Sites** on a Domino 9 server.  I have a specific keyring/keyfile for a Positive SSL certificate, however, it can only be applied to one domain name per IP.  There are other domains hosted on the same Domino server and do not need SSL.  But the original keyfile/keyring is no longer stored anywhere (named keyfile.kyr).

How should I recreate this default keyfile?  I don't want to touch the working SSL keyfile (which has another file name).

From a Notes client, I am using **Server Certificate Admin** db to **Create a new Key Ring**.  After entering the details for the new keyring keyfile.kyr I get a warning message that a keyring file has already been created.  Is this a problem?  Will the current keyring still be there?

With the server configured for Internet Sites, I should be able to assign the SSL keyfile to one domain, and the default keyfile.kyr for the rest of the domains.

I suppose I am looking for confirmation before proceeding.  Is this the right way to go?

Comment: you need the kyrtool, Server certificate admin is not used anymore... here is an [old documentation](https://abdata.ch/create-ibm-domino-keyring-file-with-sha-256-signed-certificates/), now you need to get kyrtool from HCL, but otherwise this is the way to go now...